# Network speeds on computer ran via CAT6 are DEVASTATINGLY low

Tags: networking, performance, router, upload

I recently contacted Spectrum Customer Service in regards to this question and once I got off the phone with someone who didn't know what they were talking about, I had no answer.
The plan we pay for is the Ultra Internet Speed plan advertising these perks :

- Speeds up to 400 Mbps
- FREE Internet modem
- No data caps
- FREE unlimited access to nationwide out-of-home WiFi
- FREE antivirus software

(NOTE: I do understand that our internet isn't **ALWAYS** going to be running this optimal.)
The wireless router we have is the Netgear R6400v2 with an advertised capable speed of up to 1750 Mbps. And the other router we have or the "modem" is the new standard router for our "Ultra Internet" Plan.
Despite the specifications of what we run inside the house, I come to the problem that whenever I run  a speed test on my iPhone 12 Pro Max, I get download speeds of 180 Mbps - 260 Mbps and 13 - 20 Mbps upload speed. Which is not so great considering that was ran 10 times RIGHT next to the wireless access point. The REAL problem is my computer which first of all is connected by CAT6 via a Netgear powerline adapter which caps speeds of around 940 Mbps. I have ran an absurd amount of speed tests, via Google, Spectrum's website https://www.spectrum.com/internet/speed-test, including other ones such as speedtest.net and fast.com and to top it all of I get an average of 0.6 Mbps - 26 Mbps download speed on average with a upload speed of 13 - 20 Mbps.

(NOTE: We have another computer in the office room which is also a desktop and it is connected via Wi-Fi and gets average download speeds of 25 - 45 Mbps FASTER THAN MINE and I'm on CAT6, its upload speed is around the same as my computer though??!???!)

I understand that I will not consistently get speeds of 400Mbps and I also understand that I will not receive anything OVER 400Mbps, but receiving 0.6 Mbps - 26 Mbps on average is extremely frustrating. Would anyone have any solution to this problem?

Comment: for the record, Spectrum is notoriously problematic with their infrastructure.  You are connected through their modem directly on a wire, yes?

Comment: iwell offtopic, because this is clearly an end user question.

Comment: I do indeed know that Spectrum is extremely inconsistent, but more consistent or better ISPs do not support our location like Verizon Fios. And I am connected to the third port on the Wireless Access Point (The Netgear WAP) and the Spectrum modem is right next to it but I am not connected on a power line on that.

Comment: @djdomi not sure what you are getting at, don't quite understand your grammar/spelling sorry.

Comment: move a laptop to the modem from your provider, connect lan csble to the modem and laptop and test your speed

Answer (score 1):

You seriously need to reduce complexity to track down such a problem. Judging from your description, you're currently troubleshooting this setup:

```
Spectrum router <-> Netgear R6400v2 <-> Powerline Adapter <-> Powerline Adapter <-> Laptop
```

with the suspected Cat-6 cable in between the Powerline Adapter & Laptop (or the routers, or Netgear & Powerline, doesn't matter). Unless that cable is damaged or DIY you can most likely rule it out.

Instead of that long chain, connect your laptop to the Spectrum router. If that's bad call Spectrum (or maybe test another, known good cable). If it is OK, test behind the Netgear next. And so on.

My money is on the Powerline run.